# Notify progress in asynchronous long jobs in asp.net core with signalR and async await keyword

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

In my asp.net core 2.1 web app i have an admin section where i execute long operation as sync tables from one to another database.

I use Signalr to notify the client the progress.
All works (client and server) but the notification of progress is never executed.
Only the end of job is notified (100% jobs completed)
I notice that the problem is a counter inside the loop that is not increased during job.
I think is because async code and new thread.
So with a view to understand better i simplify the problem at minimum level
and hope someone will help to solve and to understand.

```
private async Task PerformBackgroundJob(string jobId)
    {
        var taskList = new List<string>
       {
          "task1", "task2", "task3"
       };

        int processed = 0;
        foreach (var task in taskList)
        {
            switch (task)
            {
                case "task1":
                    await DoSome1();
                    processed++;
                    break;
                case "task2":
                    await DoSome2();
                    processed++;
                    break;
                case "task3":
                    await DoSome3();
                    processed++;
                    break;
            }
            await _hubContext.Clients.Group(jobId).SendAsync("progress", processed / taskList.Count * 100);
        }
    }

    private async Task DoSome1()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }

    ...
```

I would during job the percentage is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with SignalR in here. You simply divide `int` by `int` getting results as `int` rounded to zero, ie:

- (1 / 3 = 0) * 100 = 0
- (2 / 3 = 0) * 100 = 0
- (3 / 3 = 1) * 100 = 100

Just change `int processed = 0;` to `double processed = 0;` and you will get 33.33, 66.67 and 100.00.

Comment: im shame :(   is stupid error. Could i delete this post? my god...what a shame

Comment: i think of numerous problems; read tutorial ,...documentations... my god

Comment: It's a pretty valid example for SignlaR PoC for any programmer so consider leaving it be. Maybe someone will stumble upon it too. :)

Comment: but two days in that problem... ho ho ho ... no no no ... so tks man and see you soon